# Marrakesh w/ Sora STI shifters & Alivio Trekking FD + Crankset 48T

Tags: crankset

https://salsacycles.com/bikes/marrakesh/2020_marrakesh_sora
This seems to have managed to somehow got around difference between MTB & Road STI triple problem that many reported. Is it because these are Trekking components?
Want to convert from double to triple 48T or 46T. I already have a triple Sora STI being used as double.

Comment: So you have double Sora now, and you want to go to a triple setup?

Comment: Yes, I want to turn my Montague Navigator back into triple with Hollowtech Trekking or MTB crankset with STI Sora levers. As far as I know, STI cable pull  is different from MTB. So, this will not work. Wondering how Marrakesh accomplished this.

Comment: Also heard that MTB triple crankset spacing is different from Road as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the Shimano compatibility docs, the Alivio shift levers SL-M4000 are compatible with both the MTB RD/FD-M4000 and trekking RD/FD-T4000 versions of the derailleurs, so there is functionally no difference between the M and T versions.

Compatibility charts are here: https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-432&acid=C-445

Shimano used a common derailleur actuation ratio for MTB up to 9 speed and road up to 10 speed, so I'm not surprised that the Sora drop bar shifters work with Alivio derailleurs.

if you want to fit Alivio cranks and derailleurs to a frame that is nominally a road bike you have to be aware of crank spacing, bottom bracket shell width and chainline (and what bottom bracket type you have.) The Alivio cranks want a MTB style Hollowtech BB that fits 73mm (or 68mm with spacers) shells, and provides a 50mm chainline.

Specs are here: https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/TREKKING/Front%20Chainwheel

Comment: Thank u much. I had horrible shifting with Alivio FD when I changed to Sora 50/34, but likely because FD should have been 2 speed as well. So, FD & crankset on MTB & roads are interchangeable up to 9 speed. Learned something new.
Oh, one caution. I could NOT make barrel adjusters to work with MTB FD on my bike. Tension was likely too high on MTB FD & road barrel adjusters were loosened up in few days.